# porque no me suma las columnas

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando sumar la columna peso y mostrarlo en mi `<span id="ptotal">` el problema es que siempre me retorna cero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$(document).on('keyup','#datatable-buttons input.peso',function(){
                peso = $(this).val();

                sumar();
        });

    function sumar(){
            pesostotal = 0;
            $("#datatable-buttons tr").each(function(){
                pesostotal = pesostotal + $(this).find('td:eq(2)').text();
                alert(pesostotal); // lo puse por debugger Muestra 0 siempre!
            });
            $('#ptotal').text(pesostotal);
        }
```

> html

```
<table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" role="grid" aria-describedby="datatable-buttons_info" style="width: 100%;">
                          <thead>
                            <tr role="row">
                                <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-buttons" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 50px;" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Name: activate to sort column descending">#</th>
                                <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-buttons" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 200px;" aria-label="Position: activate to sort column ascending">Calidad</th>
                                <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-buttons" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 50px;" aria-label="Office: activate to sort column ascending">Peso</th>
                                <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-buttons" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 50px;" aria-label="Age: activate to sort column ascending">Cajas</th>
                                <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-buttons" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 50px;" aria-label="Start date: activate to sort column ascending">Precio</th>
                          </thead>

                            <tbody>
                                <?php if(!empty($calidad)): ?>
                                    <?php foreach($calidad as $calidad): ?>

                                  <tr role="row" class="odd">
                                      <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1"><input type="hidden"><?php echo $calidad->id; ?></td>
                                      <td><?php echo $calidad->nombre; ?></td>
                                      <td><input type="number" name="peso" placeholder="0" class="form-control peso"></td>
                                      <td><input type="number" name="cajas" placeholder="0" class="form-control cajas"></td>
                                      <td><input type="number" name="precio" placeholder="0" class="form-control precio"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: cual es el codigo html relevante?

Comment: probablemente el error es porque asi tenas un numero el lo lee como string vas a tener que parsearlo

Comment: listo, lo he añadido

Comment: cambia esa linea esto `parseInt($(this).find('td:eq(2)').text());`

Comment: con parseInt como me dijiste, me manda _NaN_

Comment: Creo que el problema es la forma en la que obtienes el dato no debería ser `find('td:eq(2)').text()` sino `find('td:eq(2)').val()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He cambiado tu código considerando en primer lugar el caso de como obtienes el value lo haces con `text()` y que lo deberias hacer con `val()` porque es un input. Por otro lado puedes utilizar el mismo selector para sumar tus inputs `#datatable-buttons input.peso` cosa que cambie y que por ultimo deberías validar si  el valor que sumaras es o no  un valor validado ya que sino lo haces se  volverá un NaN tu variable `pesostotal`

```js
$(document).on('change', '#datatable-buttons input.peso', function() {
  sumar();
});

function sumar() {
  var pesostotal = 0;
  $("#datatable-buttons input.peso").each(function() {
  
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value == "" || isNaN(value))
      return
    pesostotal += parseFloat(value);
    //alert(pesostotal); // lo puse por debugger Muestra 0 siempre!
  });

  $('#ptotal').text(pesostotal);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" role="grid" aria-describedby="datatable-buttons_info" style="width: 100%;">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-buttons" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 50px;" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Name: activate to sort column descending">#</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-buttons" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 200px;" aria-label="Position: activate to sort column ascending">Calidad</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-buttons" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 50px;" aria-label="Office: activate to sort column ascending">Peso</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-buttons" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 50px;" aria-label="Age: activate to sort column ascending">Cajas</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-buttons" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 50px;" aria-label="Start date: activate to sort column ascending">Precio</th>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1"><input type="hidden"></td>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td><input type="number" name="peso" placeholder="0" class="form-control peso"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="cajas" placeholder="0" class="form-control cajas"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="precio" placeholder="0" class="form-control precio"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1"><input type="hidden"></td>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td><input type="number" name="peso" placeholder="0" class="form-control peso"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="cajas" placeholder="0" class="form-control cajas"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="precio" placeholder="0" class="form-control precio"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1"><input type="hidden"></td>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td><input type="number" name="peso" placeholder="0" class="form-control peso"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="cajas" placeholder="0" class="form-control cajas"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="precio" placeholder="0" class="form-control precio"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<label id="ptotal"></label>
```

Comment: perfecto me diste una solución efectiva y bien explicada. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el valor dentro de tu `td` no está en el `html` del propio `td` sino en un `input`. Tienes que acceder al `children` del `td` y luego al valor de `input` (o buscar el `closest` `input`, lo que mejor te venga). Tienes también que transformar el valor a número para que no te lo tome como texto y lo concatene (en este caso he usado `Number()`).

Te dejo un ejemplo resumido:

```js
$(document).on('keyup','#datatable-buttons input.peso',function(){
  peso = $(this).val();
  sumar();
});

function sumar(){
  pesostotal = 0;
  $("#datatable-buttons tr").not(':first').each(function(){
    pesostotal = pesostotal + Number($(this).find('td:eq(2)').children().val());
  });
  $('#ptotal').val(pesostotal);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" role="grid" aria-describedby="datatable-buttons_info" style="width: 100%;">
                     <thead>
<tr role="row">
  <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-buttons" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 50px;" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Name: activate to sort column descending">#</th>
  <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-buttons" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 200px;" aria-label="Position: activate to sort column ascending">Calidad</th>
  <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-buttons" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 50px;" aria-label="Office: activate to sort column ascending">Peso</th>
  <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-buttons" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 50px;" aria-label="Age: activate to sort column ascending">Cajas</th>
  <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-buttons" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 50px;" aria-label="Start date: activate to sort column ascending">Precio</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
<tr role="row" class="odd">
  <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1"><input type="hidden"></td>
  <td>
  </td>
  <td><input type="number" name="peso" placeholder="0" class="form-control peso"></td>
  <td><input type="number" name="cajas" placeholder="0" class="form-control cajas"></td>
  <td><input type="number" name="precio" placeholder="0" class="form-control precio"></td>
</tr>
<tr role="row" class="odd">
  <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1"><input type="hidden"></td>
  <td>
  </td>
  <td><input type="number" name="peso" placeholder="0" class="form-control peso"></td>
  <td><input type="number" name="cajas" placeholder="0" class="form-control cajas"></td>
  <td><input type="number" name="precio" placeholder="0" class="form-control precio"></td>
</tr>
<tr role="row" class="odd">
  <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1"><input type="hidden"></td>
  <td>
  </td>
  <td><input type="number" name="peso" placeholder="0" class="form-control peso"></td>
  <td><input type="number" name="cajas" placeholder="0" class="form-control cajas"></td>
  <td><input type="number" name="precio" placeholder="0" class="form-control precio"></td>
</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input id="ptotal" type="text"/>
```

Comment: con $('#ptotal').text(pesostotal); me manda _NaN_ y con val() como tu lo hiciste me manda 0.

Comment: ¿Y qué valor tiene "pesostotal"?

Comment: Te devuelve NaN porque faltaba quitar el primer tr (el correspondiente al thead) con $("#datatable-buttons tr").not(':first'). Estaba intentando entonces coger el val del children pero no existía.